# Why IE Keeps sessions alive?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer, session

Hy all!

I'm developing a MVC 4.0 web application with C# and came accros the following error.
In major browsers (Chrome, Mozilla Safari, etc...) when i click logout in my web application it does the correct, logout the current user.
When i do the same operation on IE, dosen't work, i login with the new user, and IE keeps the last user until i press ctrl+F5.
The only thing i'm using for authentication is Sessions, nothing more.

Someone came acrros this issue? i've tried clear cache, clear sessions with abadon, clear, removeall and nothing seems to work when i'm on IE.

If you guys need some more info to help me with that, i'll answer as soon as possible!!

Comment: Is this behavior happening in your environment with a IIS application server or just locally?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following works:

```
Session.Clear()                                                                
Session.Abandon()                                                              
Session.RemoveAll()                                                            
If Request.Cookies("ASP.NET_SessionId") IsNot Nothing Then                     
    Response.Cookies("ASP.NET_SessionId").Value = ""                       
    Response.Cookies("ASP.NET_SessionId").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-20)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, browsers implement it so that ctrl+f5 means "make an http request for the current url, without the **browser** cache). So, no matter what you do after the fact in your server-side code, because IE is by default reloading the current page from its local memory without even hitting your server, you will not appear logged out. Then, when it does eventually go back to your server, it's still sending the same cookie because the page that would have logged you out is never actually hit.

One way to test if this is happening, is to set a breakpoint in your logout code. Refresh the page without holding `ctrl` in IE, and see if the breakpoint is even hit. If it's not, then you know client-side caching is the cause.

Workarounds:

This code on the server will send the page with metadata indicating the browser is not allowed, under any circumstances, to cache the page on their side:

```
response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
response.Cache.SetNoStore();
response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
```

-- or --

When you go to your logout page with a link like this: `/logout` or `/home?logout=1` add an extra paramter like this: `/logout?cacheBust=123yt74y5t`, making the last part random. This works because most browser caches will cache based on url, so if you randomly mess up an unimportant part of the url, you can get around it. One advantage to this method is that you actually want the browser to cache some pages, but not others, and this is a more client-side way of determining if you want a fresh copy from the server or not.